# How to encrypt database password before sending to server using Spring MVC datasource context?

Tags: spring, sybase, sap-ase, spring-jdbc, password-encryption

I am having a Spring MVC application that connects to Sybase 15.5 server. Now the database server has been upgraded to Sybase 15.7 and they have set Password Encryption ON in the server. Means, the client should encrypt the database password before sending it to the database server. I have the password in my properties file.

The question is, how can I encrypt the password in the spring context file before sending to the database server?

Current Spring Context file:

```
<!-- ========================== Data Source [Start] ================================================================== -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${jdbc.initialPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}"/>
    <!-- <property name="timeout"><value>0</value></property> -->   <!-- 0 means: no timeout -->
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>200</value></property>
    <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>1</value></property>
    <property name="maxStatements"><value>0</value></property>  <!-- 0 means: statement caching is turned off.  -->
    <property name="numHelperThreads"><value>3</value></property>  <!-- 3 is default --> 
</bean>
<!-- ========================== Data Source [End] ==================================================================== -->
```

Comment: If using Hibernate, I think you can use Jasypt for this: http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html - For Spring integration, check http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html

Comment: No. I am not using Hibernate.

Comment: You need only to encrypt the password and the server is responsible for decrypting, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an inner bean to encrypt your pwd before sending it. Do they require a certain method for encryption?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the url approach finally. This makes use of com.certicom.ecc.jcae.Certicom' class for the encryption.

Steps:

1. Edit the jdbc url in the properties file like below
   jdbc.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:hostname:port/databasename?ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=TRUE&JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS=com.certicom.ecc.jcae.Certicom
2. Place the below 3 jars file in the build path.

   EccpressoFIPSJca.jar, EccpressoFIPS.jar, jconn4-7.07.jar

This will make use of these APIs to encrypt the database password before sending it over the wire to Sybase 15.7 server. Hope this helps. Thanks.